# this is my code and it appears "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" why?

Tags: mongodb

l have an error when running the code
this is my code and it appears **"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"**

```
 import com.mongodb.*;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 public class test_3{   
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        DB myDb ;
        DBCollection myCollection = null;
         Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost",27017);
         myDb=mongo.getDB("test_company");   
         myDb.getCollection("login");
         System.out.println((myCollection.find()).toString());   
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test_3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 

         null,ex);
         }

        }
         }
```

Comment: What is the line that throws the exception?

Comment: this line :
  System.out.println((myCollection.find()).toString());

Comment: And if I change the code to this : 

 
     

     
    try {
        DB myDb = null ;
        DBCollection myCollection = null;
        
         DBCursor curser=(myDb.getCollection("login")).find();
        while(curser.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(curser.next());}
        
         Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost",27017);
         myDb=mongo.getDB("test_company");   
     
         
      
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(test_3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 

         null,ex);
         }

       
the first error happen :(

Comment: It's hard to read code this way. You should probably add this code snippet to your original question and format it in the same way...

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer is `myCollection`, which you've initialized but never assigned a value later on. I assume you meant to assign the return value from `myDb.getCollection()` ?

Comment: I want to return the feilds in myCollection

Comment: mmm , I modified the order to : 
 System.out.println(myDb.getCollection("login").find().toString()); 
but the output was :
Cursor id=0, ns=test_company.login, query={ }, numIterated=0, readPreference=primary

what is mean?

Comment: Having no knowledge of Mongo, I have no idea. You should seek out some example code that shows how to get the data you're trying to retrieve...